# JComboBox within JTable not saving selection

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable which contains a `Name` and `Choice` column. I would like for the `Choice` column to contain a `JComboBox` Component that has the same selection for every row, although allow for independent selection for every unique row.

Currently, interacting with the `JComboBox` within the column allows for the drop-down to appear for a selection to be made; although, no selection is saved.

[image]

Instead, the selection made migrates to any `JComboBox` that I click on. E.g., I click on the first row's `JComboBox` and select "Choice B", but all choices still appear as "Choice A". It isn't until I click on another row's `JComboBox` that the drop-down appears with the "Choice B" selection highlighted.

The code used for this table is as follows:

```
final String[] choices = new String[]{"Choice A", "Choice B", "Choice C"};
final Collection<String> mockData = Arrays.asList("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth");
table.setModel(new MasterTableModel(mockData.stream().map(s -> {
    return new Object[]{s, new JComboBox<>(choices)};
}).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
table.setDefaultEditor(JComboBox.class, new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox<>(choices)));
table.setDefaultRenderer(JComboBox.class, new MasterTableComboRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(JComboBox.class)));
```

I have three choices, which are used to initalize `JComboBox`es that populate the `Choice` column.
I set the `DefaultRenderer` to my custom `MasterTableComboRenderer` object which implements the `TableCellRenderer` interface so as to have the `JComboBox` show up as a `Component` rather than to print the address of the object. It only requires the overriding of a single method:

```
class MasterTableComboRenderer ...
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(final JTable table, final Object value, final boolean isSelected, final boolean hasFocus, final int row, final int column) {
    return value instanceof Component ? (Component) value : renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
}
```

Finally, `MasterTableModel` is a simple extension of `AbstractTableModel`, which defines the column headers `[Name, Choice]` and holds an `Object[][]` reperesenting the `JTable`'s data.
I've overriden `isCellEditable` and `getColumnClass` as follows:

```
class MasterTableModel...
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {
    return getColumnName(columnIndex).equals("Choice");
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(final int columnIndex) {
    return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
}
```

Is there something I've been missing to achieve the functionality of the `JComboBox` saving its choices and not having the selection highlight migrate to other boxes?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

A `JComboBox` should NOT be stored in the `TableModel`. The `String` value is stored in the model.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a Combo Box as a Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) for a working example.

If you want the renderer to look like a combo box, then you need to use a combo box as a renderer. Something like:

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer
{
    public ComboBoxRenderer()
    {
        setBorder(null);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        removeAllItems();
        addItem( value );

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've attempted extending my renderer with JComboBox but it has the same functionality, while just displaying the address to that object when the drop-down is not open

Comment: You don't extend your renderer. You create a new renderer and implement the TableCellRenderer interface. *while just displaying the address to that object* - what address? Did you not read my first statement. I can't offer any more help until you post your [mre] showing how you have implement the suggested changed. And not you do NOT need a custom TableModel for the "MRE". Also, the renderer should just be added to the specify column. It should NOT replace the default renderer.